# Dynamically generate label for checkbox in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, twirl, play-bootstrap

I am quite new to Scala and the play framework and have problems generating a label for a checkbox in a form. The label is generated using the play framework (2.6.10) and its twirl template engine. I am also using the [play-bootstrap](https://adrianhurt.github.io/play-bootstrap/) library.

The following is a simplified version of my `form.scala.html`.

```
@(enrolForm: Form[EnrolData], repo: RegistrationRepository)(implicit request: MessagesRequestHeader)

@main("Enrol") {
    @b4.horizontal.formCSRF(action = routes.EnrolController.enrolPost(), "col-md-2", "col-md-10") { implicit vfc =>
        @b4.checkbox(enrolForm("car")("hasCar"), '_text -> "Checkbox @repo.priceCar")
    }
}
```

I am unable to "evaluate" the `@repo.priceCar` part. It is just not evaluated and I get the literal string "@repo.priceCar".

According to [the play framework documentation regarding string interpolation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates#String-interpolation), I should use `$` instead of `@`, but that doesn't work either.

When I leave out the `"` around the string I get all sorts of errors.

I would appreciate a hint on what I have to do.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but have you tried something like `s"Checkbox ${repo.priceCar}"`?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Yes, it is working. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not to worry! I'll write an answer so others can find a solution if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the compiler is reading the String literally as `Checkbox @repo.priceCar`.

You will need to either add Strings together or use String interpolation to access this variable, as `@` is not a valid escape character in normal Scala Strings:

```
@b4.checkbox(enrolForm("car")("hasCar"), '_text -> s"Checkbox ${repo.priceCar}")
```

This is injecting the variable `repo.priceCar` into the String, rather than just reading `repo.priceCar` literally as a String.

Answer (score 0):

In general when you want to place a variable within a string you use `$`:

```
var something = "hello" 
println(s"$something, world!")
```

Now, if there is member like `user.username` you need to use `${user.username}`:

```
println(s" current user is ${user.username}")
```

So overall, you need to use the escape character `@` within the Playframework's views, when you use the variable so it will be:

```
s" Current user: ${@user.username}"
```

Therefore the `'_text` value should be as following:

```
'_text -> s"Checkbox ${repo.priceCar}" //we drop the @ because the line started with '@'
```